# SSL Error on using ESRI arcgis python api

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, arcgis, esri

For my company's project, i need to use ESRI arcgis python API to access the data in our Enterprise ArcGIS portal.
After installing the arcgis library, i did a test of the connection via GIS().
the code looks as below

```
gis = GIS( profile="link to the portal",username ="username",password="password",verify_cert = False ,proxy_host='username:password@proxy_host',proxy_port=proxy_port)
```

But it gives me an error as below

```
Please set verify_cert=False due to encountered SSL error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.arcgis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sharing/rest/generateToken (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

The error still exists even though i set **verify_cert = False**
Also i tried to set the proxy in the environment beforehand

```
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "http://proxy"
```

No luck as well.
my openssl version is **OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021**-
It's very appreciate if anyone could provide me some solutions

Answer (score 2):

we managed to get past this error by downgrading urllib3 to 1.25.11 in the python virt env after installing arcgis, using `pip install urllib3==1.25.11`

then connected using out proxy `gis = GIS(the_url, verify_cert=False, proxy_host="our.proxy", proxy_port=port_num)`